# Intuitive explanation of perspective vs. projection in geometry

Tags: math-history, projective-geometry, plane-geometry

I was wondering if someone could please explain the intuition of the distinction between *perspective* and *projection* in geometry. Chapter 8 of John Stillwell's *Mathematics and its History* begins by pointing out that the original motivation for the study of projective geometry was the technique of perspective painting that was developed in the fifteenth century, and his short summary of what it means for "two points to be in perspective" from a given point makes perfect sense to me. However, I am somewhat confused by Exercise 8.3.1, which asks for a proof that any three points on a line can be sent to any other three points on a line by projection. Clearly, it is not the case that any three points on a line can be in perspective with any other three points on a line (since the point of one's perspective would need to be the point of intersection of the lines through the three pairs of points, and three lines do not in general intersect at the same point). After referring to the solution of the exercise in question, I noticed that it states:

> Let $p, q, r$ be three points on a line and $p', q', r'$ be three other points on a line. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $p = p'$ and then define a projection from the point of intersection of the lines through $q$ and $q'$ and through $r$ and $r'$, respectively.

I would like to develop a deeper understanding of why we can assume $p$ and $p'$ to be the same point in this context, since it is stated explicitly that $p$ and $p'$ are arbitrary points. Based on what little I understand of this topic, I believe that it relates to the formal distinction between the real projective line $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and the real projective plane $\mathbb{RP}^2$, something that is not made especially clear in this section of Stillwell's book. What I am seeking here though is some sort of explanation that does not draw on the formal algebraic properties of $\mathbb{RP}^1$ and $\mathbb{RP}^2$, but rather one that is based entirely on geometric intuition, as in the example of perspective painting.

Comment: We are free to move the lines PQR and P'Q'R'. In other words, the exercise means: given two lines PQR and P'Q'R', show that there is a way of placing these lines in a plane so that there is a point O for which P'∈OP, Q'∈OQ, R'∈OR.

Comment: @ViktorBlasjo Many thanks for your reply. If I may ask a follow-up question, how would the procedure that you mentioned involving "moving" the lines PQR and P'Q'R' so that P and P' can ultimately be considered the same "point" relate to the notions of projection and perspective?

Comment: By projection do you mean projectivity?

Comment: @gpassante My lack of familiarity with this subject matter unfortunately limits my understanding of the distinction that you have drawn between projection and projectivity. Exercise 8.3.1 in Stillwell's book asks to "show that any three points on a line can be sent to any other three points on a line by *projection*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single projection cannot suffice, as you observed. I think the problem wants to transform the triple $(P, Q, R)$ neatly into the triple $(P', Q', R')$ by means of projection operations only.
Denoting by $l$ and $l'$ the lines containing the two given triples, this can be done by considering the translation

$$ t\;:\;X \longrightarrow X + (P'-P) $$

which send $P$ in $P'$, restricted to $l \to t(l)$, and composing it with the projection of center the point $C$ of intersection of the lines

$$ Q' + t(Q) \quad\text{and}\quad R'+t(R) $$

between lines $t(l)$ and $l'$.

The translation $t$, restricted as mentioned, may be considered a projection from a point at infinity, precisely the point $\langle(P'-P,0)\rangle$, if $P'\neq P$.
Point C can also be a point at infinity.

Comment: Thank you, this really helps to clarify things - especially your final comment about the translation $t$ being considered a perspective view from a point at infinity. In Section 8.2 of Stillwell's book, it is written that "iteration of perspective views gives a projective view," so in this instance, I assume that the composite map defined in your solution amounts to an iteration of two perspective views - the first from a point at infinity and the second from the point of intersection of the line through $Q'$ and $t(Q)$ and the line through $R'$ and $t(R)$.

Comment: Really glad to have been helpful. Ciao!!